# Split String in Java with regex

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am getting an input from the user as a String, input example are like this:

```
Hospital name 123-4567   (Hospital name = name, 123-4567=ZIP CODE)
Hospital 123-4567        (Hospital = name, 123-4567=ZIP CODE)
Hospital 33name 123-4567 (Hospital 33name = name, 123-4567=ZIP CODE)
123-4567                 (123-4567=ZIP CODE)
1234567                  (1234567=ZIP CODE)
```

Now I found a regex to recognize the ZIP CODE: `[0-9]{3}[-,ー]?[0-9]{4}`
(first are 3 number, then 4 number after -,ー)
But I want to split the string in 2 parts: name and zip code.
If I split with this regex the string: HOSPITAL NAME 123-4567

I get a variable with only: HOSPITAL NAME, and the ZIP CODE isn't "divided" in another variable / list.

I have to separate the 2 parts in 2 different variable / list / array, everything is fine.

Than is not all, in the user inputbox, every character inputted is processed, so
I have to recognize the string on every input.

If the user start to input: HOSPITAL NAME 3 (I can guess that this 3 is the start of the ZIP CODE or still the name of the hospital, but if the input continue with: HOSPITAL NAME 345-, I'm sure that 345- is the ZIP CODE)

Anyone know how to DIVIDE this sting in 2 parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `inputLine` is a single line to parse (e.g. `Hospital name 123-4567`)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:(.*)\\s+)?(\\d{3}[-ー]?\\d{4})"):
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputLine);
matcher.matches();
//use matcher.group(1) for the hospital name (e.g. "Hospital name")
//use matcher.group(2) for the zip code (e.g. "123-4567")
```

This regex will work for your purposes.

Comment: "Hospital" at the start of the string was an example, I dont know the name of the hospital, it can be: Luxur Hospital 123-4567 or DentistName 123-4567 etc...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize. I have fixed it now.

Comment: It won't work unless you change all of the \\ to \ and then paste it because to use regex in java all \ in a regex has to be "double escaped" into \

Comment: Accepted, One more thing if you can, now if I input: name 123-456 everything works fine, but if I input only "name" it give me error: no matches, I want also that if the user only input the name give me a match.

Comment: Trying to make it flexible for the full thing, ONLY name, or ONLY zip code is very hard to code in regex without getting pretty complicated. I tried to spend a few minutes creating something that would achieve this but had no luck. Making the regex this "loose" can incorrectly match for a lot of stuff. Is this functionally **crucially** needed?

Comment: Yes I need this features, the user EVERY character that input in the textbox I have to check if it is a name or a zip code and check on the Database for a comparison.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend you seperate the two regexes into zip code and hospital name and go from there.

Comment: The facts is that if I only input: "name" I get no matches, but I want match with just name and postal code null is ok

Comment: So to clarify, you are fine with it detecting ONLY name or BOTH name and zip code and not being able to detect ONLY the zip code?

Comment: I'd like to detect ONLY the name or ONLY the postal code and also BOTH, sorry seems really hard.. Input example: "name" (detect name) - "name 2" (detect name and postal code 2) - "name 345" (detect name and postal code 345) - 1234 (detect postal code only) - "name a2 3456" (detect name and postal code 3456)

Comment: I think I've just fixed using some if and other regex, thank you ;)